# Error applying the if/else statement in java

Tags: java

I'm having problems with my code and hope someone can see what I'm missing.  My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;

class Boat{

    String boatName = (" ");
    boolean sailUp = false;

}

public class Project2{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("\n");

        Boat[] boatArray;

        boatArray = new Boat[args.length];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; ++i){

            boatArray[i] = new Boat();

        }

        for(int j = 0 ; j < args.length ; ++j){

            boatArray[j].boatName = args[j];

        }

        for(int k = 0 ; k < args.length ; ++k){

            String firstLetter = boatArray[k].boatName.substring(0, 1);

            if(firstLetter == ("B")){

                boatArray[k].sailUp = true;

            }else if(firstLetter == ("C")){

                boatArray[k].sailUp = true;

            }else if(firstLetter == ("N")){

                boatArray[k].sailUp = true;

            }else{

                boatArray[k].sailUp = false;

            }
        }

        for(int l = 0 ; l < args.length ; ++l){

            System.out.println("\nThe " + boatArray[l].boatName + " is ready to sail...");

            if(boatArray[l].sailUp == false){

                System.out.println("\n\tbut the sail is down, raise the sail!");

            }else if(boatArray[l].sailUp == true){

                System.out.println("\n\tthe sail is up, ahead full!");

            }           
        }
    }
}
```

I want the following output:

C:\Documents and Settings>java Project2 Enterprise Challenger Discovery Nimitz

The Enterprise is ready to sail...

```
    but the sail is down, raise the sail!
```

The Challenger is ready to sail...

```
    the sail is up, ahead full!
```

The Discovery is ready to sail...

```
    but the sail is down, raise the sail!
```

The Nimitz is ready to sail...

```
    the sail is up, ahead full!
```

But I get this:

C:\Documents and Settings>java Project2 Enterprise Challenger Discovery Nimitz

The Enterprise is ready to sail...

```
    but the sail is down, raise the sail!
```

The Challenger is ready to sail...

```
    but the sail is down, raise the sail!
```

The Discovery is ready to sail...

```
    but the sail is down, raise the sail!
```

The Nimitz is ready to sail...

```
    but the sail is down, raise the sail!
```

Why isn't the sail state being reset by the third loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
firstLetter == ("B")
```

to

```
firstLetter.equals("B")
```

etc

`==` checks for reference equality, where as `.equals` will check value equality

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!  I've only been in this class for four weeks and was not even aware of this method.  I HAVE A LOT TO LEARN!  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Strings are objects, so you compare them using `equals` method ("C".equals(firstLetter)), not `==`.

Also, if you only need one character, you can extract char (using `charAt(int)`) and compare to 'A', 'B', etc. (this time using `==` :) ) e.g.:

```
char firstLetter = boatArray[k].boatName.charAt(1);
if(firstLetter == 'B'){
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this, it is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method 'equals', or 'equalsIgnoreCase' when working on objects of type *String*
A '==' (also referred to as C-style equality) attempts to compare the object reference instead.

Something like this

```
if( "B".equalsIgnoreCase( firstletter ) ){
// do whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this, it is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
== -> checks for equality in reference.

equals -> checks for equality in value.
```

So try using equals method instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this, it is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you compare an object to another object , you have to use .equals() method but not "==" .
"==" will compare the two string's pointer .

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this, it is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use string.equals() like that

```
if(firstLetter.equals("B")){

       boatArray[k].sailUp = true;

}else if(firstLetter.equals("C")){

       boatArray[k].sailUp = true;
}else if(firstLetter.equals("N")){

       boatArray[k].sailUp = true;

}else{

       boatArray[k].sailUp = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this, it is appreciated!